# Java application Swing drawing no Snake

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have programmed the game "Snake" in Java, but when I execute my program my snake does not appear. When I run my application, the game appears with writing, colors, and the apple the snake should eat. Just not the snake.

The program is here: https://github.com/ryanhillman/Colorful-Snake

[This is what comes up when I run my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNP2q.png)

Can anyone figure out what is causing my game to start incorrectly?

Thank you

Comment: Don't expect people to follow links to an entire project. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).